# Any alternative solution for web analytics other than cookies to get 100% accurate data?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, cookies, google-analytics

Cookies are commonly used in most of the existing web anlytics. `Eg:Google Anlaytics`,

`Drawbacks:` Suppose user had disabled the cookies in browser. Then how come web analytics collects the user interaction data in case of cookies used in web analytics.

[we can't get the 100% accurate data](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/data-quality-sucks-lets-just-get-over-it/.) even by using cookies in web analytics

[Can we use analytics with the new UK cookie law?](http://blog.silktide.com/2011/05/can-we-use-analytics-with-the-new-uk-cookie-law/.)

Is there any other alternate solution to collect `100% accurate data` in web analytics other than cookies?

Comment: If cookies are disabled some fuzzy logic is applied to discern between visitor sessions but obviously repeat visitors are impossible to track in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Am I showing my age when I say "log file analysis" ? This will give you an accurate number for page impressions. You cannot have 100% accurate numbers for "unique visitors" and other aggregated values because that's to some extent a matter of definition and differs between systems.

Comment: Probably log file analysis is good in this scenario but its lacking [Event Tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics#Click_analytics)

Comment: We cannot track [Traffic source and  length of time a user spends on your site](http://www.webalizer.org/simpleton.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% accurate, because like cookies a user can disable it, but a place I previously worked was migrating to a JavaScript based system. I don't know how well the data turned out to be, because I left before we get results back, but you could look at [OWA's JavaScript Tracker](http://demo.openwebanalytics.com/jstracker.php)

Comment: OWA's javascript Tracker  also depends on [cookies](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Tracker#Cookie_Domain_and_Sub_Domain_Tracking)